# How can I get my Verizon apple Iphone to straightalk?

Tags: iphone, cellular-carriers

I have a Verizon iPhone and I want to hook it up with Straight Talk. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I use my iPhone from Verizon (**not** unlocked by Verizon) in Thailand, where they don't provide any kind of Straight talk.
So I just disabled in Settings all sort of use of my [integrated] US number, and added my Apple ID. Thou it is now used more like iPod Touch, but I am pretty accessible true iMessage, FaceTime, Viber, Facebook, etc... And all this only when I am in a Wi-Fi reachable area.

---

So IMO, to not use Verizon services with Verizon iPhone - this would be one option to do so...

Answer (score 0):

Your iphone has to be unlocked by Verizon.

Pending your contract they might or might no do that.

After that there is no problem using Straight talk.